# Special Venn Diagram - TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the interior regions for `C` and `not C`. What are the tools to use?

[image]

### Update regarding the first comments

Here is my first attempt, where I would like to round only the corners of the fill shapes that correspond to the rounded corners of the rectangle.

[image]

The code used is the following one.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill, blue] 
        (0,0) -- (0, 2cm) --
        (2.5cm,2cm) 
            .. controls (1,1) and (1,1) .. 
        (2cm,0cm);

    \draw[fill, orange] 
        (4cm,0) -- (4cm, 2cm) --
        (2.5cm,2cm) 
            .. controls (1,1) and (1,1) .. 
        (2cm,0cm);

    \draw[ultra thick,rounded corners]
        (0,0) rectangle (4cm,2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using `rounded corners` on the filled shapes is not satisfying, even if we ignore the starting corners of the paths.

[image]

One solution could be to draw one filled shape by using one rounded rectangle overlapped by one smaller "Bézier" shape. Is there a cleaner solution ?

Comment: Patterns, path picture, clipping, possibly finding intersections or even spath3. Depends on how complex C and not C and their borders are …

Comment: The path should be similar to the one in the picture, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I will close my question and come back here in case of failure.

Comment: The straight forward way would be to construct a path out of the blue border and the border between C and not C which you can then use a pattern on. For that you need the path between C and not C to start exactly at the blue border since you then just need to concatenate these segments. But clipping against the blue path might just be the easiest.

Comment: Independently of the form of C's border, if it is a simple closed curve, you can solve the problem with `fill` on C, and `even odd rule` on C and the universe to get the exterior of C.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I have updated my question by adding one M(almost)WE.

Comment: @DanielN I have proposed a simplistic solution. I will try to use your proposal later (I have to go to work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`rounded corners`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-paths#pgf.rounded:corners) can be used on only parts of a path:

> You can switch the rounded corners on and off “in the middle of path” and different corners in the same path can have different corner radii:
>
> ```
> \begin{tikzpicture}
>   \draw (0,0) [rounded corners=10pt] -- (1,1) -- (2,1)
>                      [sharp corners] -- (2,0)
>                [rounded corners=5pt] -- cycle;
> \end{tikzpicture}
> ```

Though, instead of `sharp corners`, you can also use a group.

And since you're only filling the are of one path you can use indeed use a `path picture` here which would clip the corners on the sharp areas for C and C̅.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill, blue] 
    {[rounded corners] (0, 0) -- (0,   2)} % ← a group
                              -- (2.5, 2)
        .. controls (1, 1) and (1, 1) .. (2, 0)
    [rounded corners] -- cycle;            % ← rest of the path

\draw[fill, orange] 
     [rounded corners] (4, 0) -- (4,   2)
     [sharp corners]          -- (2.5, 2)  % ← switch back
        .. controls (1, 1) and (1, 1) .. (2, 0)
     [rounded corners] -- cycle;           % ← and forth

\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners]
    (0,0) rectangle (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz
\draw[ultra thick,rounded corners]
    (0,0) rectangle (4,2)[path picture={
        \draw[fill, blue] (0, 0) |- (2.5, 2) 
                .. controls (1, 1) and (1, 1) .. (2, 0)
          -- cycle;
        \draw[fill, orange] (4, 0) |- (2.5, 2) 
                .. controls (1, 1) and (1, 1) .. (2, 0)
              -- cycle;
    }];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I am also consistently using coordinates in the [*xyz* coordinate system](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#pgf.xyz) (without units). There are good reasons to mix them with the *canvas* cs but they don't apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'm a little padawan. Thanks also for the two approaches in your solution.