# How can I draw a shape with overlapping regions with opacity?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Can anyone help making this shape but you can change the length, width of each sections.
(and I want to be able to fill, opacity and change the length, width of it).

This is just my rough drawing.

[image]

I attempted by combining three sections like this but it doesn't work well. The overlap region doesn't work with opacity.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=red,draw=none, rounded corners, line cap=round, opacity=0.3] (0,0) rectangle (1cm,4cm);

\draw[fill=red,draw=none, rounded corners,  line cap=round, opacity=0.3] (0,0) rectangle (4cm,1cm);

\draw[fill=red,draw=none, rounded corners, line cap=round, opacity=0.3] (3cm,0) rectangle (4cm,4cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should this be a shape as in a node of that shape or do you just want an easy way to form a path in that U shap? What are its dimensions, how is it defined?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel shape as in node. I tried node but only do rectangle.

Comment: If you just want to use it like this, not as a node, you can create a `transparency group`: `\begin{scope}[opacity=.3, transparency group, rounded corners] \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,4); \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (4,1); \fill[red] (3,0) rectangle (4,4); \end{scope}`.

Comment: @hana: Can you provide a more descriptive title rather than using "How to draw this shape?"

Comment: @Werner do you have any suggestion for the title? I don't know how to say it.

Comment: @hana: What is the main problem here? Use that as inspiration.

Answer (score 22):

This approach does not create a node, but may still be of some help on the path to the final solution. Make use of a `transparency group`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[opacity=.3, transparency group, rounded corners] 
    \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (1,4); 
    \fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (4,1); 
    \fill[red] (3,0) rectangle (4,4); 
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

You can also use it as a `pic`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    u shape/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[transparency group, rounded corners] 
            \path[#1]
                (0,0) rectangle (1,4)
                (0,0) rectangle (4,1)
                (3,0) rectangle (4,4); 
        \end{scope}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pic[opacity=0.3] at (0,0) {u shape={fill=green}};

\pic[rotate=30, opacity=0.25] at (3,2) {u shape={fill=red}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Since you want to be able to change height and width:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
    pics/u shape/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{u shape/.cd, #1}
            \path[rounded corners, pic actions]
                (0,0) -- ++(0,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/height}}) 
                    -- ++(1,0)
                [sharp corners]
                    -- ++(0,{1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/height}})
                    -- ++({\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/width}-2},0)
                [rounded corners]
                    -- ++(0,{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/height}-1})
                    -- ++(1,0)
                    -- ++(0,{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/height}})
                    -- ++({-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/u shape/width}},0)
                    -- cycle; 
        }
    },
    u shape/.cd,
    width/.initial=3,
    height/.initial=2,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \pic[fill=red] at (0,0) {u shape};
    
    \pic[fill=green, rotate=30, opacity=0.5] at (0,-2) {u shape={width=5, height=3}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice figues.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you really need, but here's a start. However, it is *not* a node shape. That's a bit more work to get it right (it involves PGF), but just with plain TikZ and a few tricky internals and the `fit` library, we can create a rectangular node with the given text and then use that node in reference and draw that U-shape around it.

For this, the `Unode = {<width>}{<path usage>}` key is used where `<width>` specifies the width of that U and `<path usage>` specifies the usage of that path (`draw`, `fill`, `pattern`, `opacity`, …).

You can use the `every Unode` style for common styles between many of these shapes.

With the `fit` library, another rectangular node will be placed so you can use it as normal, with the line stopping outside the whole shape.

With a selective `sharp corners` the rounded corners can be [switched off for part of a path](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667102/16595). I'm also using the `<width>` argument to set the rounded corners' radius to be always on the safe side, but you can, of course, set it to any other value.

---

You can't use the outer shape as a reference to place the whole shape. If you use `anchor` at the node, the anchor of the main/inner node will be used to place the whole construct.

This could have also been implemented with a `pic` with a slightly different syntax … but I thought of that too late.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\tikzset{
  Unode/.style 2 args={
    shape=rectangle, path only,
    append after command={
      \pgfextra{%
        \pgfmathanglebetweenpoints{\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{west}}
                                  {\pgfpointanchor{\tikzlastnode}{east}}%
        \let\unodeFitRotate\pgfmathresult
        \pgfsettransform{\csname pgf@sh@nt@\tikzlastnode\endcsname}}
      (\tikzlastnode.north west)
        edge[every Unode,#2,rounded corners={(#1)/3}, to path={
            --++ (left:{#1}) |- ([yshift={-(#1)}]\tikzlastnode.south west)
                             -| ([xshift={#1}]\tikzlastnode.north east)
                             -- (\tikzlastnode.north east) {[sharp corners]
                             |- (\tikzlastnode.south west)} -- cycle}] ()
      node [path only, inner sep=+0pt, rotate fit=\unodeFitRotate,
        fit={([xshift={-(#1)}]\tikzlastnode.north west)
             ([shift={({#1},{-(#1)})}]\tikzlastnode.south east)}]
        (\tikzlastnode-f) {}}},
  every Unode/.style={draw=none, fill, fill opacity=.5}}
\begin{document}

\tikz\node[Unode={.3cm}{red}]{hana};

\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\Huge]
\draw[help lines] (-1.5,-1.5) grid (6.5,2.75);
\node[Unode={.5cm}{green!50}]                                    (foo) {Foo};
\node[rotate=45, anchor=west,
      Unode={.7cm}{left color=red, right color=orange}] at (4,1) (bar) {Bar};
\draw[thick] (foo-f) -- (bar-f);
\path[font=\small, every pin edge/.style={thick, blue, <-}]
      (0,0) coordinate[pin={$(0,0)$}] (@)
      (4,1) coordinate[pin={$(4,1)$}] (@);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks great, especially `Foo` and `Bar`. Probably I  didn't understand the difference between node and path. I want to use it as background for something.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add the simplest solution, You can just use `\draw` with `line width` set to `1cm` (or whatever).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red, opacity=.3, line width=1cm, rounded corners](0,3)--(0,0)--(4,0)--(4,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You could add `line cap=round`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: I considered it, but that creates a semicircle cap. Do you know a simple way to get rounded corners there?

Comment: Yes, this is true. Maybe using a (custom) arrow tip? `arrows.meta` has `Rectangle[round]` ... but I don't know how customizable this is.

Comment: You could use `{Square[round, open, length=1cm]}-{Square[round, open, length=1cm]}` but since the arrow tip overlaps with the line, you would still need a `transparency group`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Right. I had the same thought. But then your solution would be better. Well, your solution is probably better anyway. :-)

Comment: I think, your approach is also very nice, because is needs less coordinates.