# TikZ: rounded corners only on a part of the path

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

What is the correct syntax if I only want `rounded corners=<length>` on part of the (closed) path?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw[rounded corners=5.5] (77:1.5) arc (77:180-77:1.5) -- ++(0,1) 
-- ++(-0.5,0.5) -- ++(0.5,0.5) % here rounded corners...
-- ++(0,1) -- ++(0.5,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can switch the rounded corners on partway through the path and switch them back off later:

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\draw (77:1.5) arc (77:180-77:1.5) -- ++(0,1) 
[rounded corners=5.5] -- ++(-0.5,0.5) [sharp corners]  -- ++(0.5,0.5) % here rounded corners...
 -- ++(0,1) -- ++(0.5,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, a [group can be used](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/667102), i.e. `{[rounded corners=5.5pt] -- ++(-0.5,0.5)}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Nice idea! You should post it as an answer!